# Background listener for users events/actions

Tags: android, android-intentservice

I need to create a library that works in the background of the android application and listens and records all actions/events that user uses in mobile application.

For example:

1. If user clicks on particular button, library will note that he clicked on it.
2. If user clicks on a map, library records that event/gesture
3. If user swipes , library will note that user swipe...

My library tracking usability of application, and i need some kind of listener that records action/event that user uses.

I cant find anything on web, how to catch events in background service. I read about `BroadcastReceiver`, `IntentService` cant figure out can I use this in my library for my problem.

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 1):

You can't intercept user events of other apps.

Comment: I do not want to follow another application, I want that developers can track theirs application. After importing the library, the programmer starts the service and service follow all users activity and register that events/activity. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can track the behavior of user in your application then you can do it by using the **Google Analytics** and implement it in your application.

[Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/) provides easy to use APIs and SDKs to send data to Google Analytics.

With the collection APIs and SDKs, you can measure how users interact with your content and marketing initiatives. Once implemented, you will be able to view user-interaction data within Google Analytics or through the Reporting APIs.

Comment: I need my own service for tracking my own application, not to tracking other application. Thank you for answer.

Comment: It is good solution for programmers who want to track their application. But, I need to create my own service for tracking, I need to handle number of clicks, spend time on some tasks ..